# SharePoint List Validation from a choice column to two columns

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

I am trying to validate my Calendar list in SharePoint. I have a column called **subject** which have multiple options among them we have two options, **Travel** and **Offiste**.

If **travel** is selected then another column called **State** can't be blank . 
If **Offsite** is selected then another column called  **Building** can't be blank

here is my formula which works individually but not together

```
OR(IF(Subject="Travel",IF([State] 
<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE),IF(Subject="Offsite",IF([Building] 
<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE))
```

It is not validating any now. but if i keep only one it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below forum.

```
IF(Subject="Travel",IF([State]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),IF(Subject="Offsite",IF([Building]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE))
```